# Working on Purim

Tags: purim, employment

Are you allowed to work on Purim in The United States or Israel and does it make a diffrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/266,2108189/Is-it-permitted-to-work-on-Purim.html), citing Code of Jewish Law Orach Chaim 696:1, that it is customary not to work on Purim.

Comment: I was looking for somthing with a little more meat someone told me he heard the language used about working on Purim is you do not see Siman Bracha I want to know if its Legitimate?

Comment: see here; http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9008&st=&pgnum=618&hilite=
yes, that is part of the language.

Comment: Thanx for the Mareh Makom

Comment: Josh, that is taking an outdated piece from the Rema and citing it as halacha.  Firstly, the Shulchan Aruch says it is permissible.  Secondly, the Rema is merely stating the custom at his time (which would bind everyone halachically).  Today, most people only get 10-14 days off, and there are 14 Yomim Tovim plus Tisha b'av.  Hopefully there are weekends, but practically, many people go to work nowadays and perhaps take off early.  As far as the Siman Bracha, see Magen Avraham where it may depend on the minhag.  Additionally, one on your page says no gain, but no loss.